# How to monitor complete website

Tags: website-monitoring

Can any one suggest me a that monitors websites(.net,php),mobile apps(ios,android).I googled but i'm not able to find best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://newrelic.com/

Analyze your software. Awesome-ize your business.

Built by people who deeply understand the challenges in running a modern software business, our SaaS Platform collects your data wherever it lives. All our products and capabilities fully integrate, giving you real-time information on every aspect of your software. So you can take action—instantly and intelligently.

Please find the demo for your references.

http://newrelic.com/request-demo?did=platform